# Which values of $a$ and $b$ will give $x^{2}+2$ as a factor of $x^{17}+ax+b$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

The question:

Let $x^{17}+ax+b$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$. For which values of $a$ and $b$ will $x^{2}+2$ be a factor?

I know that I can find a solution by a brute force technique, but is there a more efficient way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If $x^2+2$ is a factor of that polynomial p, then every root of $x^2+2$ will be a root of p. $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ only has 3 elements. Check which ones are roots of $x^2+2$. Then those same roots need to be roots of the polynomial. So $p(x_1) = 0$ and $p(x_2) = 0$. You get two equations with two unknowns, so you can solve for a and b.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Servaes, ok. I hesitate to write the answer when I haven't gone ahead and completed the solution. The impression I've gotten from the site is that if you're not giving a complete answer, you should stick to comments.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Opinions may differ of course, but a clear sketch of a solution is often fine too. And sometimes hints are preferable to full solutions, even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x^2+2$ is a factor of that polynomial p, then every root of $x^2+2$ will be a root of p. $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ only has 3 elements. Check which ones are roots of $x^2+2$. Then those same roots need to be roots of the polynomial. So $p(x_1)=0$ and $p(x_2)=0$. You get two equations with two unknowns, so you can solve for a and b.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. So if I wanted I could apply this same method for larger $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, right? Such as $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, or $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$, or any arbitrary size?

Comment: Sure. But in this case it is very simple to just check every element of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ because there are only 3 elements. For $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ you've got 13 elements to check, so maybe you'd want to use a different technique there, or try to eliminate a bunch of the elements as not being possible roots, so you don't have to check each one.

Comment: Great, that is also really helpful.
Okay, just so I know if I am doing this right or need to go back and re-work this problem, I found that there are no elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ for which $x^2+2$ is a factor of $x^{17}+ax+b$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Milty, no that's not correct. You should be getting 1 and 2 as roots. For example $1^2+2 = 3 \equiv 0 \mod 3$. So that's a root. and so is 2.

Comment: remember you are working mod 3.

Comment: Ahhh I see, thank you yet again!

Comment: What if there are no roots in $\mathbb{Z_3}$? E.g. $x^2 + 1 $.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I think you have to use long-division in that case. Then setting the remainder equal to zero should give you solutions for a and b.

Comment: @CalvinLin, actually Jyrki Lantonen's answer gives an excellent solution in this case. You can adapt his method by using the fact that $x^2+1|x^{16}+1$. So then we get $x^2+1|x^{17}+x$. Our remainder then becomes $(a-1)x+b$. So we get $a=1$ and $b=0$.

Comment: @AmeetSharma No. I'm asking about the general case where it's not immediately obvious that you could appeal to $ x^n \pm 1$ to simplify the term, nor is it factorable to linear terms. E.g. $ x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 1$. In the $\mathbb{C}[x]$ case, we simply evaluate at the complex roots. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent idea in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, maybe we have to go into the splitting field of that irreducible polynomial?

Comment: @CalvinLin If we are looking for the remainder modulo $x^2+1$ I would first use that $x^2+1\mid x^4-1$. All in line with the zeros of $x^2+1$ being fourth roots of unity. This would allow me to reduce all the exponents modulo $4$. At that point we would have a cubic remainder, and can find the linear remainder of the long division by using $x^2\equiv-1$, $x^3\equiv-x$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the efficient method :-)

In $\Bbb{Z}_3$ we have $2=-1$, so $x^2+2=x^2-1$. This is clearly a factor of $x^{2n}-1$ for all positive integers $n$. In particular $x^2-1\mid x^{16}-1$. Consequently
$$x^2+2\mid x^{17}-x.$$
We can deduce that the remainder of $x^{17}+ax+b$ in long division by $x^2+2$ is thus
$$
r(x)=(a+1)x+b.
$$
Obviously this vanishes if and only if $a=-1=2$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Very nice. This works well for all factors even if they don't have roots.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Well, this works for factors of $x^m \pm 1$. However, not all (irreducible) polynomials need to have such a nice form,

Comment: @CalvinLin, yes you're right.

Comment: @CalvinLin Actually over a finite field ALL irreducible polynomials are factors of $x^m-1$ for SOME $m$.  This is is because every non-zero element of every finite field is a root of unity. Your point does stand in the sense that $m$ (=the order of the said root of unity) may be uncomfortably large for the purposes of settling questions such as this.

Comment: Ok, there is the exception formed by the irreducible polynomial $x$ :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah, that's what I thought. Unfortunately I've returned most of my abstract algebra facts from lack of use.

Comment: Good job! If we wanted to extend this past the integers, to the real or complex numbers, would this method remain the same?

Comment: @Milty In characteristic zero a typical irreducible polynomial is not a factor of $x^n\pm1$. If your divisor happens to have such a form then you can still use this. Also if you divide by say $x^2+5$, when $x^{2n}\equiv(-5)^n$ for all $n$. The numbers just become a bit more awkward. The point in my reply to Calvin Lin is that for example over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ we have relations like $x^3+x+1\mid x^7-1$ and $x^4+x+1\mid x^{15}-1$. The usefulness of such results here is a bit iffy :-)

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2 + 2$ is a factor of

$p(x) = x^{17} + ax + b, \tag 0$

any zero of $x^2 + 2$ must also satisfy $p(x)$;. the zeroes of $x^2 + 2$ in $\Bbb Z_3$ are $1$ and $2$:

$1^2 + 2 = 3 \equiv 0 \mod 3, \tag 1$

$2^2+ 2 = 4 + 2 = 6 \equiv 0 \mod 3; \tag 2$

indeed

$(x - 1)(x - 2) = x^2 - 3x + 2 = x^2 + 2 \mod 3; \tag 3$

if $1$ and $2$ are roots of $p(x)$, then

$1 + a + b = 1^{17} + a \cdot 1 + b = p(1) = 0 \mod 3, \tag 4$

$2^{17} + a \cdot 2 + b = p(2) = 0 \mod 3; \tag 5$

now,

$2^{17} = 2(2^4)^4 = 2(16)^4 = 2(1)^4 = 2 \mod 3; \tag 6$

thus (5) becomes

$2 + 2a + b = p(1) = 0; \mod 3; \tag 7$

thus (4) and (7) form the system

$a + b = -1 = 2 \mod 3, \tag 8$

$2a + b = -2 = 1 \mod 3; \tag 9$

we subtract (8) from (9):

$a = -1 = 2 \mod 3, \tag{10}$

and then substitute this into (8):

$b + 2 = 2 \mod 3, \tag{11}$

whence

$b = 0 \mod 3; \tag{12}$

therefore

$p(x) = x^{17} + 2x. \tag{13}$

Note that

$p(1) = 1 + 2 \cdot 1 = 3 = 0 \mod 3 \checkmark \tag{14}$

and

$p(2) = 2^{17} + 2 \cdot 2 = 2 + 4 = 6 = 0 \mod 3 \checkmark  \tag{15}$